# Flat ordered values in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Can I, on a simple query, obtain the last NOT NULL value from a table like this?

```
ID | Name  | Inserted_at | Custom.Value1 | Custom.Value2
1  | Allan | 2017-08-01  | NULL          | NULL
1  | NULL  | 2017-08-03  | Value1        | NULL
1  | NULL  | 2017-08-05  | Value2        | Value3
2  | Jones | 2017-08-02  | NULL          | NULL
```

The value that I expect to return is some like:

```
1  | Allan | 2017-08-05  | Value2        | Value3
2  | Jones | 2017-08-02  | NULL          | NULL
```

I know that Updates on BigQuery are nearly impossible and a naive MAX/GROUP/ORDER BY does not seems to be right.

Anyone have some idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is something I've always wanted an Aggregate function for.  It can be done in MSSQL with Window Functions, but it's colossally inefficient compared to an Aggregate.  I don't know if anything like Window Functions exist for BigQuery.

Comment: why value1 and not value2?

Comment: @ChrisBerger Actually, exists [Window Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#windowfunctions) for BigQuery, but I don't know how to solve this with it...

Comment: @xQbert , my bad... just fixed :)

Comment: @AllanSene Then either of the below examples should help, I think.  The one that uses first_value() is how I would do this with a window function, but I hate the need for `DISTINCT` and the performance hit.  The ARRAY_AGG() function I had never seen before.  Looks like exactly what you need, I wish I had known it existed.  I wonder if it avoids the performance problems of window functions?

Comment: @ChrisBerger This [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) is awesome! I didn't have seen either!

I was looking for something using UNNEST, but my custom values are typed as RECORD and I dont know if could be the right choice...

Comment: Ah, now I know why I've never seen ARRAY_AGG.  It doesn't exist in TSQL.   It may be part of the SQL standard, but that doesn't mean every flavor implements it.  Boo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  ID,
  ARRAY_AGG(Name IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Inserted_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS Name,
  ARRAY_AGG(Custom.Value1 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Inserted_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS Value1,
  ARRAY_AGG(Custom.Value2 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Inserted_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS Value2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

You can try this with sample data:

```
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Allan' AS Name, DATE '2017-08-01' AS Inserted_at, STRUCT(CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS Value1, CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS Value2) AS Custom UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, DATE '2017-08-03', STRUCT('Value1' AS Value1, NULL AS Value2) UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, DATE '2017-08-05', STRUCT('Value2' AS Value1, 'Value3' AS Value2) UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Jones', DATE '2017-08-02', STRUCT(NULL AS Value1, NULL AS Value2)
)
SELECT
  ID,
  ARRAY_AGG(Name IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Inserted_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS Name,
  ARRAY_AGG(Custom.Value1 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Inserted_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS Value1,
  ARRAY_AGG(Custom.Value2 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Inserted_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS Value2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Do you think that if I put a DISTINCT clause inside this ARRAY_AGG, the query will be more efficient? Some custom values could be categories with many of different values.

Comment: If you are just looking for a single value, why would you want to use DISTINCT? In general, I would expect ORDER BY with LIMIT to perform better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first_value()`:

```
select distinct id,
       first_value(name) over
           (partition by id
            order by (case when name is not null then 1 else 2 end, inserted_at desc)
           ) as name,
       max(inserted_at) as inserted_at,
       first_value(Custom.Value1) over
           (partition by id
            order by (case when Custom.Value1 is not null then 1 else 2 end, inserted_at desc)
           ) as Value1,
       first_value(Custom.Value2) over
           (partition by id
            order by (case when Custom.Value2 is not null then 1 else 2 end, inserted_at desc)
           ) as Value2
from t;
```

Comment: In effect, I have lots of nested Custom Values, so I think that this approach, using CASE, is not viable... thanks anyway :)